# Symfony 2 Twitter and Facebook API

Tags: facebook, api, twitter, symfony

Are there good plugins for Symfony 2 to connect to the Twitter and Facebook API to receive data and interact with a user?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Note: both bundles below have been deprecated in favour of [HWIOAuthBundle](https://github.com/hwi/HWIOAuthBundle).**

- [Facebook Bundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSFacebookBundle)
- [Twitter Bundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSTwitterBundle)

A good resource for symfony2 bundles (plugins) is: [knpBundles](http://knpbundles.com/)

Answer (score 2):

try this Bundle :
https://github.com/hwi/HWIOAuthBundle

very well done

Comment: A must have, all-in-one for social connection!

Comment: @Sekai nope, I don't believe you can post.